# RxJS: How to filter an array of objects, based on another array of objects?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have one object and one array and I would like to evalutate the `pnt` object against the array of rules. If `pnt` conforms to one of the rules, it should be added to a `positiveArray`.

I would like to use **RxJS-operators** for my solution.

```
const pnt = 
    {
        "pnt_name" : "P1101_HT01",
        "base" : 1
   }


const rules = [
    {
        "key" : "pnt_name",
        "value" : "P.*"
    },
    {
        "key" : "base",
        "value" : 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution assuming that the `value`-properties in your `rules`-objects contain regular-expressions and that you really want to use RxJS (though I'm not sure RxJS is really needed here).

**[Here is my stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxr8vp?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)**

This is the relevant piece of code given you really want to use RxJS:

```
import { filter, from } from 'rxjs';

const positiveArray = [];

from([pnt])
  .pipe(
    filter((inputObject) =>
      rules.some((rule) => {
        const propertyValue = inputObject[rule.key];
        const match = new RegExp('' + rule.value).test(propertyValue);
        return match;
      })
    )
  )
  .subscribe((matchingObject) => {
    positiveArray.push(matchingObject);
    console.log('positiveArray:', positiveArray);
  });
```